# Django-filter ordering by SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

My filter looks like this:

```
class CustomUserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  has_reviews_in_area = HasReviewsInArea(name='area__id')
  has_reviews_in_venue = HasReviewsInVenue(name='venue__id')

  class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['has_reviews_in_area', 'has_reviews_in_venue', 'access_level',]
    order_by = ['id', '-id', 'average_rating']
```

The problem is that average_rating is a dynamic field created in my serializer like this:

```
average_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='average_rating')
```

Which is why I get an error that looks like:

```
FieldError at /app/users/
Cannot resolve keyword u'average_rating' into field.
```

Is there anyway I can tell django-filter to filter by my serializer field? 
I am using djangorestframework 3.2.4 and django 1.8.4. (With ModelViewsets, ModelSerializers and FilterSets)

Also, I cannot make average_rating a property on my model because it is dynamically calculated according to my filters (e.g. average rating of venue in query parameter)